# Help Needed for Outliers detection post paired T-test statistical test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, experiment-design, outliers, random-allocation

I don't know if this is a standard way od doing things so open to any suggestions, basically I have done random sampling from my population to create 2 groups Treatment & Control. I also have few dimensions for these 2 groups like gmv, qty_sold. I want to perform paired T- test to check if the 2 groups are similar across these 2 dimensions, I have a suspicion that there may be few outliers who ight cause the group means to differ, is there any way to identify such outliers if my T test leads me to reject null-hypothesis ? I want to ensure that these 2 groups are similar if not I can remove the outliers and then check again.

Edit: I am looking for guidance on what measures I can take *if* the T test shows the 2 test groups are dissimilar for one variable, how can I identify and remove data points to get a comparable group in that regard..

Comment: What makes you think that outliers drive the test to reject true null hypotheses?

Comment: @Dave they might skew the mean if they are only present in one group..

Comment: But that also pushes up the variance. I recall simulating this a few years ago and finding myself surprised by how robust (in terms of type I error rate) t-testing was to outliers.

Comment: @Dave thanks for that info, could you advice me if the test is rejected, is there a way to identify any data points driving that failure? My goal is to create comparable treatment and control group and post random sampling I want to test that

Comment: If there are such outliers, they will persist no matter how you create these groups.  If you think they will affect your results, you will want to redesign your experiment and perhaps stratify those outliers into their own groups.